# Laplace Transformation using Heaviside functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I'm not very familiar with Heaviside functions so I am struggling with this:

I'm supposed to compute $Lu$ where $u''+4u=H(x-0)+H(x-\pi)$ and $H$ is a Heaviside function.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: The Heaviside function $H(x-a)$ returns 1 if x > a, 0 if x < a and (sometimes you need) $H(a)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: You might find this MIT lecture helpful; it covers the Heaviside function (aka the unit step function) and the Laplace transform: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03-differential-equations-spring-2010/video-lectures/lecture-22-using-laplace-transform-to-solve-odes-with-discontinuous-inputs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We should start with the definition.
$$
\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\} = \int_0^{\infty}f(t)e^{-st}dt
$$
Then we can compute the Laplace transform as
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}(u'') + 4\mathcal{L}(u) &= \mathcal{L}\{H(x)\} + \mathcal{L}\{H(x - \pi)\}\\
s^2U(s) - su(0) - u'(0) + 4U(s) &= \int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}dt + \int_{\pi}^{\infty}e^{-st}dt
\end{align}

Comment: So after I integrate I get:

$s^2U(s)-su(0)-u'(0)+4U(s)$=$e^(-\pi s) \over s$ - $1 \over s$.  


But how do I simplify the left hand side without having any initial conditions to get rid of $su(0)$ and $u'(0)$?

Comment: Because if I can get rid of $su(0)$ and $u'(0)$ then I will have:

$(s^2+4) U(s)$=the right hand side, then I can divide by $(s^2+4)$ and take the inverse Laplace Transform to get the answer correct?

Comment: @user141745 many times, when we take the Laplace transform, we assume zero initial conditions if we don't have any. That is, $u(0) = 0$ and $u'(0) = 0$.